# What's wrong with pinky use in classical guitar playing/

Tags: terminology, classical-guitar

In classical guitar music, there is often an inclusion of pima referring to which plucking fingers are suggested for playing certain strings/frets/notes.

Whatever happened to pinky? Is that a frowned-upon playing finger (although I, and I'm sure others, use it at times) and if it is advocated, what's its abbreviation?

Comment: Classical guitar and tea drinking use the pinky the same way — extended outward with great sophistication?

Answer (score 5):

Common plucking fingering marks are derived from Spanish finger names: *p, i, m, a, c/x/e/q* for ***p**ulgar*, ***í**ndice*, ***m**edio*, ***a**nular* and ***c**hico* or *meñi**q**u**e***.

As you see there are multiple symbols uncommonly used in guitar notation. This is already a sign that this is not commonly used.

I guess this is the case for many reasons, some of which might involve

- Lack of independence between ring finger and pinky
- Shorter length (thus not level with the other fingers)
- Often less trained, so less controlled
- Especially when playing without nails different sound
- …

But I do not think anyone is going to oppose you using that finger, and it cannot hurt develop that finger a bit.

Comment: There are proponents of playing using all 5 fingers of the right hand. See e.g. [Štěpán Rak](http://www.stepanrak.cz/technique-stepan-rak.html), who got his tenure for his work on this technique.